# My question (on Stack Overflow) has recent activity by Community user (the background process), what does that mean?

Tags: support, community-user

A few months ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545804/creating-password-protected-pdf), and the next day I got the solution so I posted my own solution. Now, after 2 months there is activity by [Community User (the background process)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

What was the activity?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On July 21, a spammer posted a spam link as an answer. It was deleted shortly thereafter, but deleted answers still count as activity on the question. That is why it says there was activity 24 days ago.

Now, activity must come from *someone*. That spammer's account was destroyed at the same time, so that leaves no one to have performed the last activity. Thus, the system just blames the "Community" user as a default.